# DotNetOpenAuth and IlMerge

Tags: dotnetopenauth, ilmerge

Have been trying to use DotNetOpenAuth witl ILMerge and having some trouble.
At first was resulting in Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Net.Http.
so I added a reference to it,  that results in Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Web.Mvc.  Added a reference to System.Web.MVC and had it copy to the output directory, still a problem.  so I added /lib:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies"
and it just goes downhill from there.   HAs anyone been successful using IlMerge with DotNetOpenAuth ?